# Submit button not changing text when all fields are validated and clicked

Tags: javascript, html

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>checkbox </title>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
              <label for="name"><span class="stileTesto">Nome</span></label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="surname"><span class="stileTesto">Cognome:</span></label>
              <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="comment">Scrivi la tua idea!</label>
              <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button  id="bottone" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
    </body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }


  input[type="text"],
  input[type="email"],
  textarea {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  textarea[name="comment"] {
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  
  button {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #f36709;
  }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validateFields() {
    // Get the values of the input fields
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    const surname = document.getElementById("surname").value.trim();
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    const comment = document.getElementById("comment").value.trim();

    // Check if any fields are empty
    if (name === "" || surname === "" || email === "" || comment == "") {
      alert("Please fill in all fields.");
      return;
    }

    // Check if the email address is valid
    const emailRegex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
      return;
    }

    // If all fields are valid, change the button text to "Thanks!"
    document.querySelector("button").textContent = "Thanks!";
  }
```

everything is working fine except for that the button isn't changing from "submit" to "Thank you". I tried changing the type from submit to button but apparently nothing changed.
the text gets submitted correctly but I'd like it to change so it makes it more clear to see that it's submitted.

Comment: What does `submitForm()` do?

Comment: Also where do you run/trigger the `validateFields()`

Comment: @Konrad sorry that's a typo. it shouldn't be there. it's from a previous try. i'll edit immediately.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I would have placed it in the html under the form but I think I'd screw it up. is it the problem?

Comment: Try to use document.getElementById('bottone'), as query selector probably returns an array of one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want to achive, but I would change the type of your button and then add the event to your submit button.

```
<button id="bottone" type="button" onclick="validateFields()">Submit</button>
```

Then you just need to trigger your submit if the conditions are approved. I've added the code in the js.

**Demo**

```js
function validateFields() {
  // Get the values of the input fields
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
  const surname = document.getElementById("surname").value.trim();
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
  const comment = document.getElementById("comment").value.trim();

  // Check if any fields are empty
  if (name === "" || surname === "" || email === "" || comment == "") {
    alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    return;
  }

  // Check if the email address is valid
  const emailRegex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
    return;
  }

  // If all fields are valid, change the button text to "Thanks!"
  document.querySelector("button").textContent = "Thanks!";
  //document.querySelector("form").submit();
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

textarea[name="comment"] {
  height: 150px;
}

button {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #f36709;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="name"><span class="stileTesto">Nome</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="surname"><span class="stileTesto">Cognome:</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="comment">Scrivi la tua idea!</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="bottone" type="button" onclick="validateFields()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want the submit button to 1. submit the fields. 2. change his text to "Thanks!" when all the fields are compiled correctly and submitted. the code that you shared fixed my problem, but now the fields wont "submit" and they stay there. Still, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @greglama in the last part of the js code i added `//document.querySelector("form").submit();` remove the `//`

Comment: look like it works! just one more doubt. is there a way I can know if the content is actually getting submitted ?(dont have a database where the data is getting stored right now)? (i see the button changing so my problem is solved!)

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript code just add

```
const bottone = document.getElementById(“bottone”);
bottone?.addEventListener(“click”,validateFields())
```

Because you need to get the object with id “bottone” and then add an event that, when someone click the button, do something and in this case is run your function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateFields(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the values of the input fields
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    const surname = document.getElementById("surname").value.trim();
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    const comment = document.getElementById("comment").value.trim();

    // Check if any fields are empty
    if (name === "" || surname === "" || email === "" || comment == "") {
      alert("Please fill in all fields.");
      return;
    }

    // Check if the email address is valid
    const emailRegex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
      return;
    }

    // If all fields are valid, change the button text to "Thanks!"
    document.querySelector("button").textContent = "Thanks!";
  }
```

```css
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }


  input[type="text"],
  input[type="email"],
  textarea {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  textarea[name="comment"] {
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  
  button {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #f36709;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>checkbox </title>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="validateFields(event)">
            <div>
              <label for="name"><span class="stileTesto">Nome</span></label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="surname"><span class="stileTesto">Cognome:</span></label>
              <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="comment">Scrivi la tua idea!</label>
              <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button  id="bottone" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
    </body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

There is some step you have to do:

1. Apply your validateFields function to html form.
2. Take the event.
3. Apply this "**e.preventDefault();**" code to your JavaScript validateFields Function code.